# Hangs up the application while processing the request

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, request

There was such a question, why, when sending a GET request, does the application hang? How to fix it?

I understand that the thing is asynchronous, but I don’t understand what to do with it.

That is, when sending a GET request, the site completely hangs for 1-2 seconds.

**articles.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Article {
  title: string;
  collection: string[];
  description: string[];
  links: string[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ArticlesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles(url) {
    return this.http.get<Article>(url);
  }
}
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article, ArticlesService } from '../../services/articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers: [ArticlesService]
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articlesServices: ArticlesService) { }

  searchQuery: string;
  articles: {};

  static getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&profile=strict&search='
      + searchQuery + '&limit=100&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  showArticles() {
    this.articlesServices.getArticles(SearchComponent.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: Article) => this.articles = Object.values({ ...data })
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**search.component.html**

```
<div class="search-form mt-2 input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Поиск"
        [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
        (keyup.enter)="showArticles();">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button (click)="showArticles()"
            class="btn btn-search btn-outline-secondary"
            type="submit">Search
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<app-articles [articles]="articles">
</app-articles>
```

**articles.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="articles">
  <div class="ml-2">
    <h4>По запросу <small class="text-muted">"{{ articles[0] }}"</small>
      найдены статьи:</h4>
    <h6>Количество статей: {{ articles[1].length }}</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="article-block" *ngFor="let article of articles[1]; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="let link of articles[3]; let k = index" [hidden]="i != k">
        <a class="link-article" [attr.href]="link">{{ article }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="article-description" *ngFor="let description of articles[2]; let j = index" [hidden]="i != j">
      <div *ngIf="description !== ''; else missingSnippet">{{ description }}</div>
      <ng-template #missingSnippet>Not found</ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: added component templates

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you question is... Could you please rephrase.

Comment: @AJT_82 When a GET request is sent, the entire site freezes for about 1 second, I would like to fix it.

Comment: Well not seeing the template, we don't know what is going on there. One solution that is very common, is to show a spinner while fetching data.

Comment: @AJT_82 I edited the question and added component templates

Comment: If you mean with `app hanging` meaning that nothing is shown while data is fetched. You have the *ngIf that would be causing this. So, either a spinner could be an option, or route resolver: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Comment: Check the network request with your browser's inspector. You trigger a request for each letter typed into the input field. This likely creates a storm of requests with huge results sets (as the result set for short search terms is big), clogging up your network connection and your CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better UX would be to show the user a ***Loading...*** message till the time you get the results. Ghost Animations are quite common these days.

But for simplicity's sake, just show the user a loading message while the articles are being fetched from the API.

You'll have to change your template like this:

```
<div class="search-form mt-2 input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Поиск"
        [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
        (keyup.enter)="showArticles();"
        (change)="showResults = false">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button (click)="showArticles()"
            class="btn btn-search btn-outline-secondary"
            type="submit">Search
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div *ngIf="showResults">
  <app-articles *ngIf="articles; else elseCase" [articles]="articles">
  </app-articles>

  <ng-template #elseCase>
    Loading...
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

And your Component Class like this:

```
...

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  showResults = false;

  searchQuery: string;
  articles: any[];

  static getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&profile=strict&search='
      + searchQuery + '&limit=100&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  showArticles() {
    this.showResults = true;
    this.articlesServices.getArticles(SearchComponent.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: Article) => { 
          this.articles = Object.values({ ...data });
        }
      );
  }

  ...
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wikipedia-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.ts) for your ref.